# jQuery - add images text descriptions

Tags: jquery, gallery

I used a very nice JQuery downloaded from here:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/10/07/slider-gallery/

and this is what I've done:
http://www.massimozompa.com/home.html

Now I'm trying to add a short text as description of the big images. Somebody can help me to do it?  Thank you!

Comment: *Do it for me* questions are likely to be ignored. If you want the attention of users you should try to understand the code that generates the slider; come up with a plan to alter it and put your plan to test. If it does not achieve what you want then, explain what you did and ask for help.

Comment: You should get text from an attribute of single thumb image (for example: alt) and then copy the text inside a div on the big image, i've not see the plugin's code, but generally this is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Take another div  as below for every class="content" which consists of image description

```
<div class="content">
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/album1/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album1/1.jpg"     class="thumb"/</a>
  </div>
   <div id="description">Description about the image.........</div>
</div>
```

appply css for the div

```
#description {
display:none
}
```

Now under this code

```
<div id="fp_overlay" class="fp_overlay"></div>
<div id="fp_loading" class="fp_loading"></div>
<div id="fp_next" class="fp_next"></div>
<div id="fp_prev" class="fp_prev"></div>
<div id="fp_close" class="fp_close">Close preview</div>
```

add another div which is for displaying the description text

```
<div id="displayDescription></div>
```

Apply css as you requirement to the above div  i.e where to display...etc

Now in this function

```
$fp_content_wrapper.find('.content')
                    .bind('click',function(e){
                    var $current = $(this);
                    current = $current.index();
                    centerImage($current,true,600);
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
```

add the following code after "centerImage($current,true,600);"

```
var descriptionText=$current.children(1).text();
$('#displayDescription').text(descriptionText);
```

and also you add the above code in the following function in both if and else block after var $current=....; statement

```
function navigate(way) {
var $current = $fp_thumbScroller.find('.container:nth-child('+parseInt(gallery_idx+1)+')')
                                            .find('.content:nth-child('+parseInt(current+1)+')');
}
```

In the function  showPreviewFunctions() add the following code

```
$('#displayDescription').show();
```

And in function hidePreviewFunctions() add the following code

```
$('#displayDescription').hide();
```

You are done now.

i have done it, it is working for me...

Click if the answer is useful